# How to create "Add (Searched Item)" if the item is not found

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar

Hi i've been looking a way i can do something like this....
on a UISearchBar, type a word like "Product" and if doesn't find
in the first cell it should appear "Add (Product)" so if i tap on it, 
the new item (Product) will be created...

this is what i wanna get...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVY9Z.jpg

i've been trying to find information about adding a button by using SearchBar with Search Display Controller to do it that way.. but i didn't find anything..

Please help me! :)

Comment: if you share your code we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add a button, you should check the count of your filtered array (that you use to populate the search table), and if it's zero, add a string to that array "Add + search text". Then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you'll need to distinguish whether you selected a "normal" search result table cell, or the one you added self.addTextString to. Something like this (addTextString is a property I added):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detail"];
    if(tableView == self.tableView) {
        //do something from unfiltered table
    }
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        if ([self.filteredData[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:self.addTextString]) {
            AddProductViewController *add = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddProduct"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:add animated:YES];
        }else{
            detail.detailText = self.filteredData[indexPath.row];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
        }
    }
}


#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {

    [self.filteredData removeAllObjects];
    for (NSString *s in self.theData) {
        if ([s compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])] == NSOrderedSame) {
            [self.filteredData addObject:s];
        }
    }
    if (self.filteredData.count == 0) {
        [self.filteredData addObject:[@"Add " stringByAppendingString:searchText]];
        self.addTextString = [@"Add " stringByAppendingString:searchText];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the searched items array count is 0. If it is indeed 0 then you can either:

1. return 1 in the `-numberOfRowsInSection:` and handle the `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` appropriately

   ### or
2. insert "Add [*SearchTerm*]" and handle this appropriately